# How to convert dataset of images to tensor?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I've got a dataset of images that looks like this:

```
array([[[[0.35980392, 0.26078431, 0.14313725],
     [0.38137255, 0.26470588, 0.15196078],
     [0.51960784, 0.3745098 , 0.26176471],
     ...,
     [0.34313725, 0.22352941, 0.15      ],
     [0.30784314, 0.2254902 , 0.15686275],
     [0.28823529, 0.22843137, 0.16862745]],

    [[0.38627451, 0.28235294, 0.16764706],
     [0.45098039, 0.32843137, 0.21666667],
     [0.62254902, 0.47254902, 0.36470588],
     ...,
     [0.34607843, 0.22745098, 0.15490196],
     [0.30686275, 0.2245098 , 0.15588235],
     [0.27843137, 0.21960784, 0.16176471]],

    [[0.41568627, 0.30098039, 0.18431373],
     [0.51862745, 0.38529412, 0.27352941],
     [0.67745098, 0.52058824, 0.40980392],
     ...,
     [0.34901961, 0.22941176, 0.15588235],
     [0.29901961, 0.21666667, 0.14901961],
     [0.26078431, 0.20098039, 0.14313725]],

    ...,
```

What I need is convert it to tensor so that I could pass it to CNN.
I'm trying to do it like that:

```
from torchvision import transforms as transforms
transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        ])
```

How can I apply this `transform` to my dataset? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably want to create a dataloader. You will need a class which iterates over your dataset, you can do that like this:

```py
import torch
import torchvision.transforms

class YourDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self):

       # load your dataset (how every you want, this example has the dataset stored in a json file
        with open(<dataset-path>, "r") as f:
            self.dataset = json.load(f)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sample = self.dataset[idx]
        data, label = sample[0], sample[1]
        
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        ])
        return transform(data), torch.tensor(label)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset)
```

Now you can create a dataloader:

```py
train_set = YourDataset()

train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
            train_set,
            batch_size=64,
            num_workers=1,
            shuffle=True,
        )
```

And now you can iterator over the dataloader in your train-loop:

```py
for samples, labels in self.train_set:
    . . . 
    # samples will hold N samples of your dataset where N is the batchsize
```

If you need more explanation, take a look a pytorchs documentation on [this topic](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

After being initialized a torchvision transform can be called on a PIL image or `torch.Tensor` depending on the transform (in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html) you can find precisely what is expected by a given transform). So assuming your transform pipeline is valid (output type for each transform is compatible with input type of following transform) then you can simply call it: `transform(data)`.

This should work with your data since [`transforms.ToTensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor) can accept a `numpy.ndarray` as input

---

Alternatively, if your dataset is a little more complex than a simple NumPy array. You could implement your own `Dataset` class which would handle: image fetching in file system, performing relevant transformations, etc... Here's a rough guideline:

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyDataset, self).__init__()

        # define your data for example a list of images
        self.data = ...

        # define your transform pipline
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        ])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        path = self.data[index]
        img = Image.open(path)
        return self.transform(x)
```

*Where `Image` is imported from `PIL`*.

---

For you case, though, you would have something a little simpler:

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(MyDataset, self).__init__()

        self.data = data

        # define your transform pipline
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        ])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = self.data[index]
        return self.transform(x)
```

And you would pass your `numpy.ndarray` to the `MyDataset`'s initializer.